# I need help with an integral that is too chaotic for my level of undestsanding

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I need to find the integral of this. I was trying to do volumes of revolution across x=2 using the disc method with this equation and came up with the integral below. Help would be much appreciated.

$$
\int \left( \frac{1-(y-2)^2}{3.8^{1.2(y-2)}} \right)^{1/2.8} \, dy
$$

Comment: where from you find this problem? Some background is required

Comment: I am doing an investigation on finding the volume of a building. and this shape is one of the ornaments on the building. It was originally a figure resembling a body, but I tried to simplify it into this shape. I am ok with changing the shape if need be, but would like to challenge myself

Comment: I don't think you can do that integral any way but numerically (and for that, you'll need limits of integration).

Comment: if I have limits for when y is 1 and 3 does that help? I wanted to check if you could do it otherwise though.